# How to plot SVM time-series and cross-validate the model in R?

Tags: r, sum

I have weather dataset from 01-11-2007 to 18-05-2008 and I want to predict the max temperature from 29-04-2008 to 18-05-2008 my dataset have 200 rows and 6 variables. My dataset wasn't in order so first I converted the date column to type date so I can sort the date in order then split the dataset to 90% for training and 10% for testing. Then I normalized all my variables except for date and then I converted the date again to numerical. I then applied SVM model to my training dataset. I'm just not sure how to test for accuracy or to plot my testing data (predicted max temperature from 29-04-2008 to 18-05-2008)

```
> str(dataset)
str(dataset)
'data.frame':   200 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Date       : Date, format: "2007-11-01" "2007-11-02" "2007-11-03" ...
 $ MinTemp    : num  0.439 0.7 0.687 0.67 0.422 ...
 $ MaxTemp    : num  0.531 0.637 0.494 0.171 0.196 ...
 $ Rainfall   : num  0 0.0905 0.0905 1 0.0704 ...
 $ Evaporation: num  0.175 0.254 0.365 0.476 0.349 ...
 $ Sunshine   : num  0.463 0.713 0.243 0.669 0.779 ...


sum_model <- svm(MaxTemp~. , data=train,kernel = "radial")
print(sum_model)
sum_pred <- predict(sum_model, newdata = test ,type = 'response')
```

Comment: Fitting an SVM regression model to time-series data seems an odd choice. Even more so when the response is daily extremal temperature which will have all sorts of patterns (seasonalities, autoregressive features, correlation between max and min temp, etc.). Is this a purely educational/coding exercise?

Comment: I'm doing this as practice after reading a book. I just wanted to assume that all other temp and correlation between variables are ignored ans just focus on max temp. First I wasn't sure if my approach to the problem was right as in predict temp from x date to y date but I want to test it. Would RandomForest be better approach to this problem because I was planning to perform RF too and see the difference l. One of the reasons I chose svm regression is because I read that it's god for small data and could work with time series

Comment: Personally I'd start with something like a seasonal ARIMA model (or a suitable Bayesian model, like `prophet` or `bayesforecast`). I don't know how suitable SVM/RF models will be on time series data with strong seasonalities. Interesting question overall, I couldn't find a lot of examples where SVM/RF would be used for time series data analysis. Perhaps the experts over on Cross Validated can help with providing an answer.